# How to sort cells in a notebook based on cell tags?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, palettes

Suppose I have a notebook with cells tagged with both numbers and words with numbers always list first, and some cells without cell tags e.g.:

```
Notebook[{
Cell[ ..., CellTags->{"1","cat"}],
Cell[ ..., CellTags->{"2","dog"}],
...
Cell[ ...],
Cell[ ..., CellTags->{"7","cow"}],
...
}, notebook options ...]
```

What is the easiest way to sort the cells based on 1) cell tag numbers, i.e. the first element in the cell tag list; and 2) cell tag words, i.e. the second element in the cell tag list?

Note that there could be additional tags but the first and second tags are always number and single word. Note also there there is unlikely to be grouped cells (none at this stage), although a solution that took cell grouping into account and rendered a sorted ungrouped answer would be fine. I want a fast way to sort a notebook and render the newly sorted form. I'm thinking ideally I'd like a palette button for this.

Comment: I am generally useless at this kind of programmatic Notebook manipulation.  I appreciate questions like this because I learn a lot from the answers.

Comment: I might have another look at my answer today. I'm thinking that `Cases` is quite repetitive. Maybe just use it once on the content and then use `Ordering` would be more efficient.

Comment: I definitely didn't read this comment before I wrote my answer, but that's effectively what I did. Crumbs!

Answer (score 4):

This is actually something I am working on for real at the moment. This is what i have got so far:

```
nb = NotebookOpen["path/to/notebook.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
content = NotebookRead[nb];
NotebookDelete[nb];
```

For searching based on the number listed as the first tag:

```
sorted = SortBy[content, 
 Cases[#, HoldPattern[
     Rule[CellTags, {x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, NumberString], __}]] :> 
    ToExpression@x] &]
```

and for searching based on the word in the second tag:

```
sorted = SortBy[content, 
 Cases[#, HoldPattern[Rule[CellTags, {_, x_, __}]] :> x] &]
```

With both of these methods the untagged cells are returned first ...which is ok. Then

```
Scan[NotebookWrite[nb, #] &, sorted];
NotebookSave[nb];
NotebookClose[nb];
```

This is a little bit slow but seems to be doing the job.

**Edit**

So this code seems to be doing the job on the notebooks i needed to use this with. Would still be interested in suggestions from others.

```
ClearAll[sortNotebook];

Options[sortNotebook] = {"sortby" -> "Number"};

sortNotebook[file_String, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{nb, opt = OptionValue["sortby"], sorted},

  nb = NotebookOpen[file];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  content = NotebookRead[nb];
  NotebookDelete[nb];
  Which[
   opt === "Number", 
   sorted = 
    SortBy[content, 
     Cases[#, 
       HoldPattern[
         Rule[CellTags, {x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, NumberString], __}]] :>
         ToExpression@x] &],
   opt === "Task", 
   sorted = 
    SortBy[content, 
     Cases[#, HoldPattern[Rule[CellTags, {_, x_, __}]] :> x] &],
   opt =!= "Number" && opt =!= "Task", 
   Print["you messed up with the option names"]
   ];
  Scan[NotebookWrite[nb, #] &, sorted];
  NotebookSave[nb];
  NotebookClose[nb];
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a way to reorder Sections alphabetically and found this question, which I think I've got an answer for.

It relies on evaluating the code in a separate notebook, targeting the notebook with your cell tags. In my target notebook (`targetNb`) I have the following cells:

```
Cell["Typed Cell 1", "Item", CellTags -> {"1", "Zebra", "2"}], 
Cell["Typed Cell 2", "Item", CellTags -> {"2", "cat", "3"}],
Cell["Typed Cell 3","Item", CellTags -> {"4", "bat", "6"}],
Cell["Typed Cell 4", "Item", CellTags -> {"4", "aardvark", "8"}]
```

I built the following function:

```
reOrderTaggedItems[nb_] := Block[{allCells = Cells[nb],targetCellTags,targetCells,orderedCells},
targetCellTags =Cases[NotebookRead /@ allCells, 
Cell[__, CellTags -> q : {_, word_, __}] :> q];
targetCells = allCells[[Flatten@Position[NotebookRead /@ allCells,Cell[__, CellTags -> {_, word_,__}]]]];
orderedCells =NotebookRead /@ targetCells[[Ordering[targetCellTags[[All, 2]]]]];
Table[NotebookWrite[targetCells[[i]], orderedCells[[i]]], {i, 4}]]
```

Applying the function reorders my cells:

```
In[1]:=reOrderTaggedItems[targetNb]
Out[1]=Cell["Typed Cell 4", "Item", CellTags -> {"4", "aardvark", "8"}], 
Cell["Typed Cell 3", "Item", CellTags -> {"4", "bat", "6"}], 
Cell["Typed Cell 2", "Item", CellTags -> {"2", "cat", "3"}], 
Cell["Typed Cell 1", "Item", CellTags -> {"1", "Zebra", "2"}]
```

I'm currently looking into doing this for Section cells, but correctly handling the `CellGroupData` which will be slightly trickier.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based a on Martin John Hadley's. It uses `Cells` so one need at least V9 for that. But it is quite compact:

```
cellSortByTag[nb_, tagOp_: ToExpression] := Composition[
    (SelectionMove[#, Cell, All]; NotebookWrite[nb, #2]) & @@@ # &,
    Transpose,
    { #, 
      NotebookRead /@ SortBy[#, tagOp @ CurrentValue[#, CellTags] &]} &

    ][Cells[nb]];
```

---

---

Now you can test it:

```
NB = Array[ Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[#]], "Input", CellTags -> {ToString[11 - #]}] &,
            {10}
          ] // CreateDocument[#, ShowCellTags -> True] &;
```

You can evaluate this even inside `NB`:

```
 cellSortByTag[ EvaluationNotebook[] ];
```

If outside, you have to put proper `NotebookObject` of course. Moreover it will only affect those tagged `Cells` so you may have whatever else you want there.

If you have more tags, just add second arg to handle sorting, e.g.:

```
cellSortByTag[EvaluationNotebook[], Last]
```

Comment: Composition, @@@, and arbitrary tag patterns??? Way to make a man feel lazy. Your solution even handles the annoying way that singular `CellTags` aren't put in `List`s. +1

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley Unfortunately `NotebookWrite` alone is not enough. It works but it has some side effects, not obvious, due to incorrect usage. I had to add some things.