# How to move a cell up or down with a keystroke?

Tags: notebooks, keyboard, cells

It is very useful during refactoring to move lines around. All popular IDEs or text editors have this feature (PyCharm, Vim, Sublime, etc..) for example in Xcode you press: ⌥⌘[ or ⌥⌘] to move lines up and down.

**Question:** Is there a shortcut for reordering cells like this, i.e. moving the cell your cursor is in up one cell or down one cell? Effectively, this would be the same as cutting the current cell and pasting before the previous cell or after the next one.

Comment: I guess you would need to get the list of `Cells` and bind the reordering to some key strokes

Comment: But say you have a huge notebook, don't we just want to look at the nearby cells? @MikeHoneychurch

Comment: related: [66626](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66626/5478)

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  Let me know if you have any problems with my code or find the need to extend it in a way that you do not know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick pass at a Palette that does this.  The same commands could be used for keyboard commands in `KeyEventTranslations.tr`.  This is not rigorously written or tested so be careful with it.

```
mover[label_, c_List] :=
 Button[label,
  With[{nb = SelectedNotebook[]},
   (NotebookWrite[nb, #2];
      SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]) &[
    SelectionMove[nb, All, Cell],
    NotebookRead[SelectedCells[nb]],
    NotebookDelete[nb],
    SelectionMove[nb, #, Cell] & /@ c
    ]
   ]
  ]

{mover["cell up", {Previous, Before}],
 mover["cell down", {Next, After}]} // CreatePalette
```

[image]

Comment: @Kuba In reverse order: (2) yes, just a way to avoid a Symbol to hold the Cell. (1) On my system I can already repeat click to move up and down more than one place, unless I (again?!) pasted the wrong code here.  Which OS do you run again?

Comment: @Kuba I tested it again, and in *my* 10.0.2 under Windows 7-x64 it works.  After `NotebookWrite` the cursor is below the newly inserted cell, and after `SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]` the original cell (in its new location) is selected.  Really weird if you're seeing something else.  I have the Suggestion Bar turned off; do you have it on by chance?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, I checked a third time.  However I'm not sure why I put `[[1]]` there and now I think it would be better without it.  If you leave that out does this work better for you?

Comment: @Kuba For me the output of `NotebookRead[SelectedCells[nb]]` is a list, e.g. `{Cell[BoxData["foo"], "Input"]}` -- to get the first `Cell` I used `[[1]]`.  I'll remove that from my answer however as it is not needed on my system and apparently breaks something on yours.

Comment: Ok, now I've patiently tested this and it seems there is a difference between V9 and V10. On `V9` `NotebookRead[SelectedCells[nb]]` gives `Cell[_]` if `SelectedCells` has length 1. I've probably tested this in hurry earlier and haven't realised that it was on 9. Nevertheless, it's better to have something more general :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm trying to add this to my KeyEvents, but having trouble, (* Item[KeyEvent["UpArrowKeyDown",Modifiers->{Control}],FrontEndExecute[{
cd = FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[]]; 
FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Previous, Cell, 2];
FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Before, Cell];
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], cd];
FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Next, Cell, 2];
FrontEnd`NotebookDelete[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]]
}]],*)

Comment: @M.R. I will attempt this a bit later.

Comment: @M.R. I gave this a try and ran into problems myself.  It seems neither `Set` nor `Function` is handled by front end evaluation and I am trying to think of another way to pass the read data back to `NotebookWrite` at the correct time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I noticed the same thing, it its unclear to me the exact subset of functions allowed in the .tr file

Comment: @M.R. I think we *could* do this with cut and paste but that will change the clipboard which is undesirable.