# Notebook key shortcut to move current cell group up/down/in/out?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, keyboard, cellgroup

How would one add (four custom keyboard-based not palette-based) shortcuts for moving the cellgroup containing the cursor up and down and in and out (akin to tab indent) relative to adjacent cells.

Here's an example of this idea working in emacs:

[image]

The key thing is that the action takes the content nested below it along for the ride, i.e. reordering branches of the notebook tree.

**Notes:**

- It would be great if it works cross-platform, but I'll settle for changes in the .tr on MacOS.
- You can assume an outline or custom notebook stylesheet
- It must work in the FE kernel to be performant
- Related but unanswered: [How to move a cell up or down with a keystroke?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73212/how-to-move-a-cell-up-or-down-with-a-keystroke)

Comment: This is no longer something I work on much, but unfortunately this is unlikely to be possible purely in the ``FrontEnd`Private`` or ``FE` `` contexts, given that the front end itself doesn't have a mechanism for rearranging the children of a `FrontEndObject` (unless things have changed in the past 4 years). This means you'll want to a) freeze notebook updates (easy) b) copy the current cell above the previous one (shouldn't be terrible with FrontEnd packets) c) delete the current cell assuming the previous worked and d) no matter what unfreeze the notebook updates. Not easy but not terrible.

Comment: How do you freeze notebook updates?

Comment: See [the FE packet list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13451/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-frontend-packet-types) for details but you use the packets `"NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates"`, and `"NotebookResumeScreenUpdates"`

Comment: @b3m2a1 That sounds right to me, but I'm not sure how they would ensure no data loss during the operation copy delete step.

Comment: @M.R. you can copy and check you got a valid `FrontEndObject` out from the FE packet (they return) before deleting, but again I think there's no way to ensure no kernel involvement

Comment: How to select the cell group faster than with a kernel call to SelectionMove?

Comment: Can you add an example? @b3m2a1

Comment: @M.R. see the answer, not optimal but not terrible

Comment: It's a great answer but it answers the problem of moving a single cell, not the OP's question of moving the current cell and its children group

Comment: @b3m2a1 Can CellInformation determine if the cell is the top of a group?

Comment: @M.R. it can, and it turns out there's a fragile solution that requires no more kernel calls where you basically use `SelectionMove` a few more times to try to select the entire cell group and previous cell/cell group, but no solution that just checks for top-of-cell group identity will work in the context of nested cell groups because you'd end up moving your cell group outside of its nested parent. I can post this fragile solution if you want, but you need to really know what you're doing to make it make sense

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes please. But I agree, a solution would have to move the cellgroup up/down to above/below the next cellgroup but only at the same level, which requires knowing the entire tree of the Notebook's cell groupings. Is there any way to establish the mapping from cells <-> cellgroup tree (level & position)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug up my old custom key events answer to get this to work, but here's the real deal, a key event to move your cell up by one which also has protection against being at the top of the notebook.

First to allow dynamic key event binding

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/\
CustomKeyEvents.wl"];
```

Then

```
AddKeyEvent[
  "u",
  KernelExecute[
   Block[
    {
     curCell,
     prev,
     contents
     },
    {curCell, contents, prev} =
     FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]],
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell],
        FrontEnd`SelectedObject[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]],
        FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]],
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Previous, Cell],
        FrontEnd`SelectedObject[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]],
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Before, Cell]
        }
       ][[{3, 4, 6}]];
    If[MatchQ[curCell, _CellObject] && MatchQ[prev, _CellObject],
     FrontEndExecute@{
       FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[
        FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[],
        contents,
        None
        ],
       FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Previous, Cell],
       FrontEnd`NotebookDelete[curCell],
       FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]]
       },
     FrontEndExecute@
      FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]]
     ]
    ]
   ],
  "Modifiers" -> {"Command"}
  ];
```

Just type Command+u and it will move the cell, even reselecting the cell afterwards to make it easy to keep copying up.

Couldn't help myself, so here's going down, too

```
AddKeyEvent["d",
  KernelExecute[
   Block[
    {curCell, next, contents},
    {curCell, contents, next} =
     FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]], 
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell], 
        FrontEnd`SelectedObject[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]], 
        FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]], 
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Next, Cell], 
        FrontEnd`SelectedObject[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]], 
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], After, Cell]
        }][[{3, 4, 6}]];
    If[MatchQ[curCell, _CellObject] && MatchQ[next, _CellObject],
     FrontEndExecute@{
       FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], contents, None], 
       FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Previous, Cell], 
       FrontEnd`NotebookDelete[curCell], 
       FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]]
       },
     FrontEndExecute@
      FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]]]
    ]
   ],
  "Modifiers" -> {"Command"}
  ];
```

### Button

M.R. wanted an example, so digging deep into the memory banks here's what I have. I can't promise it's optimal but it's only 2 calls to the front end and the process goes by without the user ever being able to see anything happen

```mathematica
Button[
 "Click Me to Move the Current Cell",
 Block[
  {
   curCell,
   prev,
   contents
   },
  {curCell, contents} =
   FrontEndExecute[{
      FrontEnd`NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]],
      FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell],
      FrontEnd`SelectedObject[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]],
      FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]],
      FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Previous, Cell],
      FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Before, Cell]
      }
     ][[{3, 4}]];
  FrontEndExecute@{
    FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[
     FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[],
     contents,
     Cell
     ],
    FrontEnd`NotebookDelete[curCell],
    FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]]
    }
  ]
 ]
```

I don't think there's a faster way to get the selection than selection move, annoyingly. If I could use `` FrontEnd`PreviousSiblingObject `` inside the call or chain some of this stuff better I think I could do this in 1 call.

I also feel like I have a vague memory of copying a cell without needing to read out its contents first? But my memory could just be faulty.

It's up to you to figure out how to work this into the `.tr` file, or you can work with the `Menu` system (I know I had some library for doing dynamic key rebinding by sticking stuff in menus a number of years back)

As for the indent / dedent problem, I had some solution for this I'd been using since 2017 which worked well for me, but who knows if the script I stuck on GitHub can still be loaded without issues (see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174904/38205))

Comment: This works great for single cells, but what about moving the current cell AND the cells grouped under it (even when they are collapsed)... Is that a simple extension?

Comment: I tried replacing Cell with CellGroup in your code but that breaks things...

Comment: This last step requires being able to select the cell or the cellgroup ONLY IF it is the root/top cell of the group below it (not the cellgroup above). Not sure if there's a way to do that?

Comment: @user5601 not without multiple calls back to the kernel